# Detecting when window scrolls past a div in Angular

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

I am working on trying to implement infinite scroll with Firestore and Angular 11.2.10. The first step is trying to detect when a user reaches the end of my item list so I can load x more items. This would go on until my query no longer returns any results.

I have a bunch of `mat-card` under a div `#main-content`.

```
<div id="main-content">
  <mat-card class="city-card" *ngFor="let city of cities | async">
    ...
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

I have seen a few examples on how this could be implement ([like this one](https://fireship.io/lessons/infinite-scroll-firestore-angular/)), but they seem to rely on having a container with `overflow-y: scroll;`. That being said, I am not interested in having an extra scroll bar at the right of my page. My understanding is that without a div handling overflow with a scroll bar, I cannot use the `(scroll)` event on my main container.

After looking at this [link](https://itnext.io/4-ways-to-listen-to-page-scrolling-for-dynamic-ui-in-angular-ft-rxjs-5a83f91ee487), I can see that `HostListener` can be implemented to listen to the entire window.

This logs "scrolling" every time I scroll on the page:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll(e: Event): void {
  console.log("scrolling"); 
}
```

However, if I try using:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll') onScroll(e: Event): void {
  console.log(this.getYPosition(e));
}

getYPosition(e: Event): number {
  return (e.target as Element).scrollTop;
}
```

I would get the error message: **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined**

On a side note, what is the advantage of putting that code as part of a Directive instead of directly in the .ts file of my component?

Answer (score 0):

To have the Event object passed into the scroll handler, you need to pass a second argument, `['$event']`, to [@HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener):

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScroll(e: Event): void {
  console.log(this.getYPosition(e));
}
```

That second argument is (from the docs), `A set of arguments to pass to the handler method when the event occurs.`